# Регулярное выражение кроме определенных строк

Tags: регулярные-выражения, apache-flex

Дано такое регулярное выражение

```
a-z[a-zA-Z0-9']*
```

Нужно чтобы выдавалось все кроме `if`, `else`, `_` , `class`.
И собственно не могу никак это сделать.

Вообщем это нужно для интерпретатора подмножества языка haskell.
http://haskell.ru/haskell.pdf
В лексической структуре есть varid.
Это нужно для flex, для распознавания varid.

Comment: А какие попытки были сделаны?

Comment: Прочитана эта страница http://skif.bas-net.by/bsuir/book_prog/node264.html

Comment: В общем можно сделать так : Распозновать сперва ключевые слова, а после идентификаторы.

Answer (score 1):

Для поиска всех подходящих токенов:

```
/\b(?=[a-z])(?!(?:if|else|class)\b)[a-zA-Z0-9']+\b/g
```

Для валидации:

```
/^(?=[a-z])(?!(?:if|else|class)$)[a-zA-Z0-9']+$/
```

Comment: Автор не называл конкретного языка программирования - откуда взялись `str.match` и синтаксис `/.../g`?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, `match` - чтобы показать, что выражение используется для выбора из строки, а не для проверки на валидность.

Comment: А где в вопросе указано, что надо делать выбор из строки, а не проверять на валидность?

Comment: @ReinRaus, сорри, не сразу понял суть твоего исправления. Было бы лучше написать комментарий вместо правки.

Comment: Кстати, под ваше выражение подойдет `lse` от слова `else`. Вероятно, это не то, что хотелось автору.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, вот именно поэтому оно указано в ответе, потому что применять то же выражение для валидации было бы неправильно. Если конкретнее, то там понадобится заменить `\s` на начало и конец строки.

Comment: "под ваше выражение подойдет `lse` от слова `else`" - нет, потому что там есть проверка на границу слова.

Comment: Позвольте нам [продолжить обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24835/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pavel-mayorov).

Comment: а, да, увидел уже. Потому и надо убрать `str.match` - что само выражение как-то теряется на фоне "обвязки"

Comment: @PavelMayorov, обновил ответ, дополнив вариантом для валидации.

Comment: Кстати, добавление `?:` было лишним - группа внутри lookahead и без него ничего не сможет захватить.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, во-первых, его добавил не я, а во-вторых, группы внутри предпросмотра тоже захватываются. По крайней мере в js.

Comment: Да, поправка: внутри группы *негативного* предпросмотра ничего не захватывается.

Comment: А предпросмотр назад вообще сам по себе не везде есть.

Comment: При чем тут предпросмотр назад? Я говорю про `(?!`, который вы использовали.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, да, я что-то не то подумал. В любом случае, группа включается в результат: `"222".match(/(?!(1))(2)+/)` получается `["222", undefined, "2"]`, а так `"222".match(/(?!(?:1))(2)+/)` - `["222", "2"]`. В любом случае, я не вижу особых причин об этом заботиться до тех пор, пока ты не собираешься эти группы использовать. Исправление с `?:` внёс ReinRaus.

Comment: Хм, и правда. Но вот еще в чем прикол: в режиме **g**lobal группы вообще не захватываются.

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если вместо match использовать replace, то захватываются :)

Comment: @PavelMayorov если есть группа и она была сопоставлена набору символов, то эта группа будет сохранена всегда и в любом движке регексов. Добавление ?: никогда не бывает лишним. В группах должны сохраняться только те данные, которые должны быть результатом работы, либо которые должны быть обратной ссылкой. В режиме g группы захватываются абсолютно так же, как и в режиме одиночного поиска.

Comment: При использовании `String.prototype.match` в режиме g группы не захватываются вообще (проверьте).

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тут видимо небольшая путаница возникла под понятием "не захватываются". В твоей трактовке [не захватываются] = [не попадают в результирующий массив], а на самом деле [захватываются] = [участвуют в вычислении выражения]. В данном случае группы никак не используются, поэтому не вижу смысла делать микрооптимизацию производительности за счёт исключения захвата.

Comment: PavelMayorov я имел ввиду не то, что сохраняющие группы никак не показываются, а то, что хоть они никак не показываются в результате match - они сохраняются движком. @Qwertiy это скорее не микрооптимизация, а удобство. Например видя сохраняющую группу я сразу предполагаю, что она где-то использована и важна для кода. Не сохраняющая группа приятнее для глаза - особенно это хорошо чувствуется в **х**-записи больших регулярок. Хотя это все лирика. Тут скорее дело вкуса, а я привык не создавать сохраняющие группы, если в них нет нужды.

Comment: А я привык использовать режим, когда захватываются только именованные группы - вот и запутался :) На сем флуд заканчиваю.